# How add another project as reference in asp net core in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I'm using vscode and asp.net core rc2 in MacOSX to develop my WebAPI application using C#. I created other projects and I want add them as reference in the WebApiProject.

Example: I want the RealProject.Domain as reference in RealProject.API. This is the folder structure:

RealProject

- RealProject.Domain
- RealProject.API

In my first try I just added the the Project name as reference in project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "RealProject.Domain": "1.0.0-*"
  }
```

but it didn't work But I believe that I need do something to generate the package of Project.Domain. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Try command `dotnet add reference '../<path_to_project>/RealProject.Domain.csproj'`

Answer (score 0):

I ran `dotnet pack` in RealProject.Domain and then `dotnet build` in RealProject.API folder.

Now everything is working.

Comment: hey I'm trying to the same, but I'm getting the error where dependency cant be resolve did you add a package.json?